# CentOS7 Server Access

Tags: centos, login

Our former SysAdmin left.  Unfortunately, he changed the main password to one of our linux servers and did not leave that with us. We've reached out with no response. Are there any other options besides completely reloading that server?  Thankfully it's just a test server and not a production server.  We do have physical as well as remote access to the server.

Comment: Hi @t0dd! Welcome to the community.  You didn't specify if you have physical access to the server, if it's hosted on a remote DC or if you have any kind of console access to it.

Answer (score 4):

If you have "physical access" to the machine and can reboot it, you can add `init=/bin/bash` to the kernel-boot-parameters, remount rw and set a new root-password with `passwd`